# Is Android BluetoothLE support two way communication between glass and mobile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My Google Glass and Mobile supports Bluetooth LE.Can I use the Bluetooth LE for two way communication between Glass and mobile.I try to send an image from Glass to mobile and again send response to Glass using bluetooth LE.Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. First, decide which device is Central; usually the smartphone should be, as it's got more resources and power. Then when the two connect, their GATT roles (Client and Server) are interchangeable at any time, because GATT roles are independent of GAP roles (Central and Peripheral). Simply issue a GATT request from any of the two applications.

Sidenote: BLE is not designed for sending images. Each radio packet contains maximum 23 bytes of application data, so imagine how many packets you need for an image.